# PCA-LDA analysis centeroids- R

Tags: r

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573178/pca-lda-analysis-r/62573914#62573914) which perfrom PCA-LDA analysis on iris dataset in R, I am trying to add the classifier group at the centeroid locationss but I get the error when I try to calculate them:

Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, , list(mean(LD1), mean(LD2)), by = Species) :
unused argument (by = Species)

Code:

```
require(MASS)
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(gridExtra)

pca <- prcomp(iris[,-5],
              center = TRUE,
              scale. = TRUE) 

prop.pca = pca$sdev^2/sum(pca$sdev^2)

lda <- lda(Species ~ ., 
           iris, 
           prior = c(1,1,1)/3)

prop.lda = lda$svd^2/sum(lda$svd^2)

plda <- predict(object = lda,
                newdata = iris)

dataset = data.frame(species = iris[,"Species"],
                     pca = pca$x, lda = plda$x)

p1 <- ggplot(dataset) + geom_point(aes(lda.LD1, lda.LD2, colour = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("LD1 (", percent(prop.lda[1]), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("LD2 (", percent(prop.lda[2]), ")", sep=""))

p2 <- ggplot(dataset) + geom_point(aes(pca.PC1, pca.PC2, colour = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) +
  labs(x = paste("PC1 (", percent(prop.pca[1]), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("PC2 (", percent(prop.pca[2]), ")", sep=""))

grid.arrange(p1, p2)

#PCA-LDA
pcdata = data.frame(pca$x[,1:2],Species=iris$Species)
pc_lda <- lda(Species ~ .,data=pcdata , prior = c(1,1,1)/3)
prop.lda = pc_lda$svd^2/sum(pc_lda$svd^2)
pc_plda <- predict(object = pc_lda,newdata = pcdata)

dataset = data.frame(Species = iris[,"Species"],pc_plda$x)

p3 <- ggplot(dataset) + geom_point(aes(LD1, LD2, colour = Species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("PCA+LDA1 (", percent(prop.lda[1]), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("PCA+LDA2 (", percent(prop.lda[2]), ")", sep=""))


grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3) 

#PCA-LDA+centroids
dt <- dataset[order(pcdata$Species),]
centeroid <- dt[, list(mean(LD1), mean(LD2)), by = Species]
 
p3a <- ggplot(dataset) + geom_point(aes(LD1, LD2, colour = Species))  +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(color=Species))  +
  geom_text(data = centeroid, aes(label = Species)) 
  labs(x = paste("PCA+LDA1 (", percent(prop.lda[1]), ")", sep=""),
     y = paste("PCA+LDA2 (", percent(prop.lda[2]), ")", sep=""))
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `centeroid <- dt[, list(mean(LD1), mean(LD2)), by = Species]` is not valid. There is no such argument as `by=` . Use `aggregate` to get the centroids:

```
centroids <- aggregate(.~species, dataset, mean)
print(centroids, digits=4)
#      species pca.PC1 pca.PC2  pca.PC3  pca.PC4 lda.LD1 lda.LD2
# 1     setosa -2.2173 -0.2880  0.04270  0.01828   7.608  0.2151
# 2 versicolor  0.4948  0.5483  0.09581 -0.03024  -1.825 -0.7279
# 3  virginica  1.7225 -0.2604 -0.13850  0.01196  -5.783  0.5128
```

The ones you want are

```
centroids[, c("lda.LD1", "lda.LD2")]
#     lda.LD1    lda.LD2
# 1  7.607600  0.2151330
# 2 -1.825049 -0.7278996
# 3 -5.782550  0.5127666
```